# how can i update SimpleCursorAdapter list view from Service class?

Tags: android, sqlite, service, background

I have used `SimpleCursorAdapter` for display the data into a list in my activity class.I am getting the `data from Sqlite DB and applying to listview`.I am inserting the data from service class.In my service class i am getting the data from WEB services and inserting latest into Sqlite mobile database this service class will run on every 5 sec's for check the latest at Web service then bring it and insert into Sqlite db.when ever the new record is inserted into Sqlite db the listview is not updating with latest inserted record.I have implemented my application as follows:

**MyActivity.java**

```
private MySqliteHelper msh;
ListView lst;
Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        msh = new MySqliteHelper(MyActivity.this);
        msh.openToWrite();
        lst = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1));
        cursor = msh.queueAll();

        String getFromDB[] = new String[]{MySqliteHelper.KEY_CONTENT1,MySqliteHelper.KEY_CONTENT2};
        int toView[] = new int[]{R.id.msgId,R.id.usrmsg};

        lst.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, cursor, getFromDB, toView));

       //calling service class
        bindService(new Intent(ShoutGetMessagesActivity.this, ShoutRepeatService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        updateList();
    }

      private void updateList(){
              cursor.requery();
               }


        RepeatService bg;
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {

                bg = ((RepeatService.MyBinder) binder).getService();

                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Connected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                bg = null;
            }
        };
    }
```

**RepeatService.java**

```
    ArrayList<NewMessages> result;
    private MySqliteHelper msh;

     private Timer timer = new Timer();
     private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 500;



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
          msh = new MySqliteHelper(this);
            msh.openToWrite();

       pollForUpdates();

     super.onCreate();
    }

        private void pollForUpdates() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("Last message ID", "====>"+MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID);

                if(MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID==null){

                    MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID="0";

                }

                result = new ParseXml().convertUsersDetails(new Generic().getLatestFromWebService(MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID));


                 for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                    String msgs =result.get(i).getMessages();
                    String msgID = result.get(i).getMsgId();
                        Log.v("messages", "------------>>>>"+msgs);
                        Log.v("messageIDs", "--------->>>>>>"+msgID);
                        msh.insert(msgID, msgs);
                    }   

            }
        }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

        Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer started.");

    }



         private void updateList(){
      cursor.requery();
       }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        RepeatService getService() 
        {
            return RepeatService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

From the above service class i am getting latest records and inserting to Sqlite db.
How can i update from this service class to View class?

please any body help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a broadcast using intent to call a function in the activity from the run() method of service

```
private void pollForUpdates() {
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("Last message ID", "====>"+MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID);

        if(MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID==null){

            MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID="0";

        }

        result = new ParseXml().convertUsersDetails(new Generic().getLatestFromWebService(MySqliteHelper.LastMsgID));


         for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            String msgs =result.get(i).getMessages();
            String msgID = result.get(i).getMsgId();
                Log.v("messages", "------------>>>>"+msgs);
                Log.v("messageIDs", "--------->>>>>>"+msgID);
                msh.insert(msgID, msgs);
            }   

    }
*************************************
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.updatelist");
sendBroadcast(intent); // finally broadcast
*************************************

}, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);

Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer started.");

}
```

And in your activity you have to receive the broadcast intent and update the list

```
 // Register Broadcast Receiver to receive broadcast intent in oncreate method

public oncreate()
{       
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.updatelist");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    msh = new MySqliteHelper(MyActivity.this);
    msh.openToWrite();
    lst = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1));
    cursor = msh.queueAll();

    String getFromDB[] = new String[] MySqliteHelper.KEY_CONTENT1,MySqliteHelper.KEY_CONTENT2};
    int toView[] = new int[]{R.id.msgId,R.id.usrmsg};

    lst.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, cursor, getFromDB, toView));

    }
};
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer but the lates record is adding at last position.is there any chance to add the lates record at first position?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Broadcast receiver in the activity, and have the service emit a broadcast whenever the data is updated. And you have to define a custom broadcast in order for this to work.

First of all.
Define your custom action like this

```
public static final String DATA_INSERTED = "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT"
```

When data is changed in the service, do it

```
Intent intent = new Intent (DATA_INSERTED);
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Initialized a custom broadcast receiver to listen to this specific DATA_INSERTED action. Override the onReceive method. In the onReceive method. You have to call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter, which also means that you need a reference to the simplecursoradapter. I will leave the broadcastreceiver implementation to you to figure out.